# Contiguous physical memory from userspace

Tags: linux, memory

Is there a way to allocate contiguous physical memory from userspace in linux? At least few guaranteed contiguous memory pages. One huge page isn't the answer.

Comment: Why do you care if it's physically contiguous?

Comment: The only reason something like this could be important is if there are DMA accesses involved. In that case it's the kernel driver that should handle this, not the userspace.

Comment: We need this for some memory/cache performance testing: fill cache lines with the same index by stepping through the memory with the step based on cache associativity and cause cache misses.

Comment: write and insmod a kernel driver?

Comment: the problem is it had to work from userspace without additional kernel modules

Comment: Why a single huge page isn't the answer then? Just do `mmap()` with `MAP_HUGETLB`, see http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/Documentation/vm/map_hugetlb.c

Comment: we've used huge pages, but the customer is asking if it can be done without it

Comment: Did this thread answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12041352/revisions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. There is not. You *do* need to do this from Kernel space.

If you say "we need to do this from User Space" - without anything going on in kernel-space it makes little sense - because a user space program has no way of controlling *or even knowing* if the underlying memory is contiguous or not.

The only reason where you would need to do this - is if you were working in-conjunction with a piece of hardware, or some other low-level (i.e. Kernel) service that needed this requirement. So again, you would have to deal with it at *that* level.

So the answer isn't just "you can't" - but "you should never need to".

I have written such memory managers that *do* allow me to do this - but it was always because of some underlying issue at the kernel level, which had to be addressed at the kernel level. Generally because some other agent on the bus (PCI card, BIOS or even another computer over RDMA interface) had the physical contiguous memory requirement. Again, all of this had to be addressed in kernel space.

When you talk about "cache lines" - you don't need to worry. You can be assured that each *page* of your user-space memory is contiguous, and each *page* is much larger than a cache-line (no matter what architecture you're talking about).

Comment: Just for completeness, how would this be done from Kernel-space? `kmalloc`?

Comment: Write a module/device driver that uses "get_free_pages" to allocate the proper (contiguous) amount of pages via. buddy system, then have that driver expose an MMAP interface to that memory. Not that you typically may have to run this right on bootup to make sure that memory isn't fragmented enough to not allow this (depending on how much memory you need) - it might fail if there is not enough.

Comment: People ask questions because they have a problem at hand they need to solve. For example Knights Landing comes with direct mapped cache in MCDRAM. If you can stick your frequently used data into the same 16gb physical range, you ensure you do not have cache collisions causing cache thrashing.

Comment: Then the anonymous mmap of hugetlb could be an answer - but OP said "the customer didn't want to do that". I'm not debating that there is sometimes need to do that - just that there are no well-defined, reliable ways to do it IN USER SPACE.Intel SPDK tries to address this issue - and has some admittedly hacky ways to do it...

Answer (score 15):

Yes, if all you need is a few pages, this may indeed be possible.

The file `/proc/[pid]/pagemap` now allows programs to inspect the mapping of their virtual memory to physical memory.

While you cannot explicitly modify the mapping, you *can* just allocate a virtual page, lock it into memory via a call to `mlock`, record its physical address via a lookup into `/proc/self/pagemap`, and repeat until you just *happen* to get enough blocks touching eachother to create a large enough contiguous block. Then unlock and free your excess blocks.

It's hackish, clunky and potentially slow, but it's worth a try. On the other hand, there's a decently large chance that this isn't actually what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

DPDK library's memory allocator uses approach @Wallacoloo described. [eal_memory.c](https://github.com/dpdk-org/dpdk/blob/master/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_memory.c). The code is BSD licensed.

Comment: Looks like DPDK is hosting their own code now. [this](http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_memory.c) seems to be the new eal_memory.c url.

Comment: Link broke again

Answer (score 0):

if specific device driver exports dma buffer which is physical contiguous, user space can access through dma buf apis
so user task can access but not allocate directly

that is because physically contiguous constraints are not from user aplications but only from device
so only device drivers should care.