# Allocating Physically Contiguous Pages from User Space in Linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, allocation

I need to allocate physically contiguous pages from user space and get back the physical address. How can I do so? I need it physically contiguous because I'm working in-conjunction with hardware that needs that.
get_free_pages as I understood is Kernel function and returns virtual address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux contiguous physical memory from userspace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401912/linux-contiguous-physical-memory-from-userspace)

Comment: I assume you mean "Physically contiguous PAGE FRAMES."