# Is memory allocated with "ftruncate" is physically contiguous?

Tags: linux, mmap, dma

Is memory allocated with "ftruncate" is physically contiguous ? . Is their a way in Linux to allocate physical contiguous memory from user space.

Comment: Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401912/contiguous-physical-memory-from-userspace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contiguous physical memory from userspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401912/contiguous-physical-memory-from-userspace)